# Export Pervasive to MySQL (C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, database, export, pervasive

i'm looking for a way to export whole database from Pervasive 11, send it and import to MySQL server. I've tried to export it to xml file but i had problems with import it to MySQL.

Any ideas?

Comment: What problems did you have?

Answer (score 1):

You really have two options:
1. Write it yourself.
2. Use a third party tool.

**Write it yourself:**
If you are writing it yourself, you need to watch out for data type differences.  Pervasive and MySQL support different data types.  If you've got a Pervasive data type that isn't directly supported by MySQL, you'll need to convert it before writing it.  Beyond that, the process is fairly simple:  Read the records, convert any data, write the record.  Repeat for all of the tables.

**Use a third party tool:**
There are several tools available that can do what you want.  They may require multiple passes to get all of the tables but that can be automated in most cases.  Tools that fall into this category include:
- Pervasive Data Integrator - http://integration.pervasive.com/
- Informatica Power Center - http://www.informatica.com/us/products/enterprise-data-integration/powercenter/
There are other tools as well.
I did find this link http://www.etltools.net/etl-tools-comparison.html but cannot speak for the completeness or accuracy of the information.  I've only used the Pervasive Data Integrator and Microsoft SSIS (when going from Pervasive to MS SQL).