# Dump Pervasive SQL to file and import in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, pervasive

How to create a Pervasive SQL dump file like the command
`mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql` does for MqSQL?

And if it is possible, how to create a MqSQL database based on that pervasive dump file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any Dump command in Pervasive SQL.  In addition, The SQL used by Pervasive SQL has differences from MySQL. 
Take a look at [Export Pervasive to MySQL (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969911/export-pervasive-to-mysql-c) for other options.